# setting tooltips for multiple range line series in highchairs

Tags: highcharts

I am attempting do some range line charts http://jsfiddle.net/uazvokx4/ like this.

```
$(function () {

  var ranges1 = [
    [1246406400000, 14.3, 27.7],
    [1246492800000, 14.5, 27.8],
    [1246579200000, 15.5, 29.6],
    [1246665600000, 16.7, 30.7],
    [1246752000000, 16.5, 25.0],
    [1246838400000, 17.8, 25.7],
    [1246924800000, 13.5, 24.8],
    [1247011200000, 10.5, 21.4],
    [1247097600000, 9.2, 23.8],
    [1247184000000, 11.6, 21.8]
    ],
  averages1 = [
    [1246406400000, 21.5],
    [1246492800000, 22.1],
    [1246579200000, 23],
    [1246665600000, 23.8],
    [1246752000000, 21.4],
    [1246838400000, 21.3],
    [1246924800000, 18.3],
    [1247011200000, 15.4],
    [1247097600000, 16.4],
    [1247184000000, 17.7]
    ],
  ranges2 = [
    [1246406400000, 16.3, 28.7],
    [1246492800000, 16.5, 27.1],
    [1246579200000, 17.5, 26.6],
    [1246665600000, 18.7, 28.7],
    [1246752000000, 20.5, 30.0],
    [1246838400000, 19.8, 31.7],
    [1246924800000, 15.5, 27.8],
    [1247011200000, 12.5, 26.4],
    [1247097600000, 13.2, 28.8],
    [1247184000000, 11.6, 25.8]
    ],
  averages2 = [
    [1246406400000, 25.5],
    [1246492800000, 23.1],
    [1246579200000, 22],
    [1246665600000, 26.8],
    [1246752000000, 27.4],
    [1246838400000, 28.3],
    [1246924800000, 22.3],
    [1247011200000, 23.4],
    [1247097600000, 21.4],
    [1247184000000, 18.7]
    ];


  $('#container').highcharts({

    title: {
      text: 'July temperatures'
    },

    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },

    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: null
      }
    },

    tooltip: {
      crosshairs: true,
      shared: true,
      valueSuffix: '°C'
    },

    legend: {
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Temperature',
      data: averages1,
      zIndex: 1,
      marker: {
        fillColor: 'white',
        lineWidth: 2,
        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    }, {
      name: 'Range',
      data: ranges1,
      type: 'arearange',
      lineWidth: 0,
      linkedTo: ':previous',
      color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
      fillOpacity: 0.3,
      zIndex: 0
    },{
      name: 'Temperature2',
      data: averages2,
      zIndex: 1,
      marker: {
        fillColor: 'white',
        lineWidth: 2,
        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    }, {
      name: 'Range2',
      data: ranges2,
      type: 'arearange',
      lineWidth: 0,
      linkedTo: ':previous',
      color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
      fillOpacity: 0.3,
      zIndex: 0
    }]
  });
});
```

I currently have the tooltip set to use shared data, however it shows for ALL series. I am wondering if there is a way to link the line and the range so I can show just the pair rather than all series in the chart.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tooltip.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) which allows to customise content of popup. Inside function you can use loops to find a related series etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by setting `enableMouseTracking:false` on the series that you don't want to show in the tooltip.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/uazvokx4/1/

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.enableMouseTracking

**Updated for comment**

So, you want individual tool tips for the main series, but you want to group the associated ranges with them?

You'll need to use the `formatter()` function.  There are probably numerous ways to go about it, but I accomplished it with this:

```
         formatter: function() {
            var ser = this.series.name;
            var i = this.point.index;
            var rangeSer = ser == 'Temperature' ? 1 : 3;
            var range = this.series.chart.series[rangeSer].data[i];
            return    ser + ': '+ this.y + '°C'
                    + '<br/>Range: '+ range.low + '°C' 
                    + ' - ' 
                    + range.high + '°C';

        }
```

Check which series you're on, specify which range that means, and then go fetch the appropriate data point.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/uazvokx4/3/

Comment: This is very close to the desired behaviour, however I am wanting to have temperature 1 and range 1 show in the tooltip together, and temperature2 and range 2 show together.

Comment: I came across this (http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/GCqsf/1/) in my searches, however I'm not a javascript expert so I am struggling to see how it might be utilised in my situation.